# Convert number to X base

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, number-systems

As an educational exercise, I would like to make this code more efficient, with fewer lines, without using other standard functions.

The goal here is to convert a number to X base and display it, (sample for hexadecimal) including 0x0 => 0, or 0x4096 => 4096.

```
int     print_hex(int number, int base)
{
    int     i;
    int     len;
    char    c;
    char    buffer[base];

    if (!number)
    {
        putchar('0');
        return 1;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < base && number > 0)
    {
        c = "0123456789abcdef"[number % base];
        buffer[i] = c;
        number /= base;
        i++;
    }
    buffer[i] = '\0';
    len = i;
    while (i--)
        putchar(buffer[i]);
    return (len);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems strange to pass `base` and call the function `...hex...()`.

Easier to use `unsigned` rather than `int`.

`if (!number)` block not needed if a `do {} while (number);` loop used.

`char buffer[base];` is the wrong sized buffer.  Need is more like "log(INT_MAX, base) + 1".

---

> to make this code more efficient,

**speed**: Code is calling `putchar()` repetitively.   The amount of processing there can well exceed all OP's code.  Reducing I/O calls should be then the goal.  E.g. Call  `fputs()` once.

```
// a fast version

int print_fast(unsigned number, unsigned base) {
  char buf[sizeof number * CHAR_BIT + 1];
  char *end = &buf[sizeof buf] - 1;
  *end = '\0';
  do {
    end--;
    *end = "0123456789abcdef"[number % base];
    number /= base;
  } while (number);
  fputs(end, stdout);
  return (int) (&buf[sizeof buf] - end - 1);
}
```

> with fewer lines,

See [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) for such.  Note that reducing lines often goes *against* efficiently.

```
// A terse recursive solution

int print_terse(unsigned number, unsigned base) {
  int count = 1;
  if (number >= base) {
    count += print_short(number / base, base);
  }
  putchar("0123456789abcdef"[number % base]);
  return count;
}
```

> without using other standard functions.

Not possible.  Some library I/O function needed.

---

How about a full featured signed one?

Note the buffer needs to be 34 for a 32 bit `int`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int print_int(int number, int base) {
  assert(base >= 2 && base <= 36);
  char buf[sizeof number * CHAR_BIT + 2];
  char *end = &buf[sizeof buf] - 1;
  *end = '\0';

  // Form the negative absolute value
  // Negatives used to cope with `INT_MIN`
  int n = (number > 0) ? -number : number;

  do {
    end--;
    *end = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[-(n % base)];
    n /= base;
  } while (n);

  if (number < 0) {
    end--;
    *end = '-';
  }

  fputs(end, stdout);
  return (int) (&buf[sizeof buf] - end - 1);
}

int main(void) {
  printf(" %d\n", print_int(0, 10));
  printf(" %d\n", print_int(INT_MAX, 36));
  printf(" %d\n", print_int(INT_MIN, 2));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
0 1
zik0zj 6
-10000000000000000000000000000000 33
```

Comment: @ken Why did you select `number` as `int`, which is often 32-bit if your goal is 64-bit?  Suggest for your **next** coding, if the goal is to "display the numbers of 64 bits." use a type that is _at least_ 64-bit like `long long, unsigned long long, intmax_t, uintmax_t` or exactly 64-bit: `int64_t, uin64_t`.  Also then be clear: are you working with signed or unsigned types?

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not handle negative numbers.  As it is, it will print nothing.  The code should be changed to either handle the negatives properly, or take `number` as an unsigned where it is not an issue.

Your use of `base` as the length of the array to store the converted number in is incorrect.  A 32-bit integer will potentially need 32 characters to display the entire number, assuming no zero byte terminator (see below).  `buffer` should be declared as a fixed size, large enough to hold the longest possible string.  You could then eliminate the `i < base` check from your `while` loop.

The initial check of `if (!number)` can be eliminated by changing your `while` loop into a `do`/`while` look.

If you're looking for brevity in code lines, the body of the loop can be reduced to two statements, although it is more readable with three or four.

The assignment of a 0 byte to the end of buffer is unnecessary in this context since you never pass `buffer` to a function that requires it.